# Clone an EC2 Instance in Hibernated State

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Windows EC2 Instance that is enabled for hibernation. I run it, configure it the way I want it, run a script and then put it to sleep (Stop-Hibernate).

When I start up the EC2 instance again, it picks up where it left off: it "wakes up" and continues running the script. Exactly what I want! (This is equivalent with closing your laptop and then opening it again: all the RAM/Processes are where you left them before closing the lid)

Now I want to clone this instance so that I have a dozen of servers that pick up exactly where that original one left off. Is that possible?

I tried creating snapshots and images but every time I create a new instance from that image the EC2 instance starts cold: like after a hard reboot vs. waking up from hibernation.

Is what I am asking even possible? I tried looking online and played around with EC2 but I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be explained by one of the limitations associated with hibernation and documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Hibernate.html#hibernating-not-supported):

> The following actions are **not supported** for hibernation:

> Changing the instance type or size of a hibernated instance

> Creating **snapshots or AMIs** from instances for which hibernation is enabled

> Creating **snapshots or AMIs** from hibernated instances

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Was not sure how to interpret those and how up to date they are. For example, creating the snapshot for instances for which iy is enabled works - it just does not save the hibernation state.

Comment: @FlowCode Yes, so probably this is what it meant.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin! Was hoping there was a way :) Are you familiar with any other platform that would let me do it ? or some 3rd party AMI? I tried Azure but that one was just horrible :)

Comment: @FlowCode Don't think there is. Hibernated instances are very limited :-(